# Node.js: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" (type string)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I am rather new to node and am having an issue that is a bit difficult for me to decipher. I am trying to make a reddit clone. The part that I am working on right now is to allow users to view posts other users have posted. I was trying to implement a new route by pasting in this bit of code

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Post.find({}).lean()
    .then((posts) => res.render('posts-index', { posts }))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
    })
})
```

However, I am getting this error when I run it:

Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Post"

It seems like something is wrong with my post.js model, but I can't identify it. Could someone review this and help me identify the triggering factor?

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  url: { type: String, required: true },
  summary: { type: String, required: true },
}, { timestamps: true });

module.exports = model('Post', postSchema);
```

Comment: What do the documents in the posts collection look like?

Comment: As @Joe asked, we need to see some example data. My guess is that you insert broken ids to the _id field, and when mongoose is fetching, it breaks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by example data..all the input going into the database is taken through local host